# How can I enable compression of 3rd party scripts to get a better Gtmetrix score?

Tags: javascript, performance, compression, gtmetrix

If I test my website on the Gtmetrix, there appear like this :

[image]

[image]

Comment: because that js from another host so you cant doing anything except don't you that widgetapi,

Comment: @Muhammad Dyas Yaskur So you mean I can't enable compasion to raise the score gtmetrix?

Comment: You can try copying that external script and hosting in your own site/server. In addition to be able to compress it, you'll also gain some added security as no one other than you will be able to modify it.

Comment: @Luis Alberto Barandiaran I want to do that from the first. But when there's the latest updated widget, it won't update

Comment: Yes that's true. As a workaround, you could create a script that checks it daily, or each X number of minutes to see if it changes, and update yours.

Comment: This is similar to [Can external resources be cached for 7 days to improve my PageSpeed score?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72787/can-external-resources-be-cached-for-7-days-to-improve-my-pagespeed-score)